# How to select one value from MySQL table row laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Database image

how can i get one value from bank_id row ?

i have two table...one is bank name with id
other is state with state name and bank_id(equal with bank table)
state table's bank_id every row have multipal value..like 1,2,3 or 9,5,7
my question is how can i get all state name where bank id ?

please help me..

mycontroler.php

```
     public function getState(Request $request)
     {


  $states = DB::table("states")
    ->where("bank_id",$request->bank_id)
    ->pluck("name","id");
    return response()->json($states);

}
```

Comment: what happens when you hit the route?

Comment: You are not using eloquent, so just `->select()` the column(s) you want

Comment: ->pluck("name","id"); is for get name and id from states table and put in dropdown  item....i want     REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' as like function which find specify id ..where bank_id contain bankId($request) in states table

Comment: You can write the same thing three times and it just makes no sense three times.  Try improving your question.

Comment: I find the right code ...thanks alll forr try ..$states = DB::table("states")->where('bank_id', 'regexp', $request->bank_id)->pluck("name","id");
        return response()->json($states);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $states = DB::table("states")
    ->where("bank_id",$request->bank_id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: ->get(); schow object object in drop down ->pluck("name","id"); is for get name and id from states table and put in dropdown  item....i want     REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' as like function which find specify id ..where bank_id contain bankId($request) in states table

Answer (score 0):

Acording laravel documentation:

```
$states = DB::table('states')->where('bank_id', $request->bank_id)->get();
```

Comment: ->pluck("name","id"); is for get name and id from states table and put in dropdown  item....i want     REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' as like function which find specify id ..where bank_id contain bankId($request) in states table